# How to add Carthage support to a SPM dependency?

Tags: swift, dependency-management, carthage, swift-package-manager

I created one Swift Package Manager dependency and I need to add a Carthage support in order that depndency later to be used with Carthage in a project. Can someone explain the steps involved in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Carthage support to a dependency that uses SPM should be the same as adding Carthage support to a dependency that doesn't use SPM. The presence of SPM support should not impact Carthage at all.

The [Carthage README](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#supporting-carthage-for-your-framework) has steps for adding Carthage support to your package. To summarize:

1. Make sure your Xcode schemes are marked as Shared.
2. Make sure `carthage build --no-skip-current` successfully builds your dependency.
3. Make sure to tag your releases with git tags.
4. **OPTIONAL:** prebuild binaries of your framework for quicker installation

Answer (score 0):

The thing is a SPM package doesn't need a xcworkspace file. See e.g. [one of my framworks](https://github.com/Blackjacx/Engine) for example. In that case using it as carthage dependency is not that straightforward or even possible.

The second thing to consider is that Apple changed the way resources, bundled with a framework are located from the app hosting the framework:

> Important
>
> Always use Bundle.module when you access resources. A package shouldn’t make assumptions about the exact location of a resource.

The main pain point here is that this struct is generated when **SPM** builds the framework but is not created when Carthage builds it. Read detailled information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package).

If both points above don't aplpy for your framework then [moshe-katz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881989/971329) is right and you can just follow the proposed setup instructions. Otherwise please tell me how that works. I already search a solution to this problem for quite some time.

**EDIT**

When you create your Swift package using `swift package init --type tool` and then open it using `open Package.swift` a folder `.swiftpm` is created which contains a .xcworkspace file together with user data. I think this is to preserve user defaults like window size and to use features like  breakpoint sharing. You could symlink this workspace to the root folder which **might** make Carthage work. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution on this? I am trying to create an xcframework from pointfreeco snapshot testing library

Comment: I actually found something and added it to the edit section. Keep me posted when it works 